# Why in this Hibernate mapping it is used @ManyToOne instead @OneToOne?

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am absolutly new in Hibernate development and I have the following problem.

I have 2 entity classes that maps 2 DB tables:

1) The first entity class (the main one) is named **KM_ProjectInfo** and map a DB table named **KM_PROJECT**.

2) The second entity class is named **KM_ProjectInfoStatus** and map a DB table named **KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS**.

So the second one represent a specific field of the first one (a status of the row representd by an instance of the KM_ProjectInfo class). Infact I have something like this:

1) **KM_ProjectInfo** class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KM_PROJECT")
public class KM_ProjectInfo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idProjectInfo;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "technology")
    private String technology;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idCountry")
    private KMCountry country;

    @Column(name = "power")
    private long power;

    @Column(name = "cod")
    private String cod;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idProjectInfoStatus")
    private KM_ProjectInfoStatus status;

    // GETTERS & SETTERS

}
```

2) **KM_ProjectInfoStatus**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS")
public class KM_ProjectInfoStatus implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idProjectInfoStatus;

    @Column(name = "foldertech")
    private Long foldertech;

    @Column(name = "folderproject")
    private Long folderproject;

    // GETTERS & SETTERS

}
```

So, as you can see in the previous snippet, the **KM_ProjectInfoStatuss** is a field of the **KM_ProjectInfo** because I want that it contains the primary key of this table as foreign key.

In the logic of my application I want that at one row of the **KM_PROJECT** table (so at one instance of the **KM_ProjectInfo** entity class) is associated a single row of the **KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS** (one instance of the **KM_ProjectInfoStatus** entity class) because it represent a specific status for the **KM_PROJECT** row.

In my code I have:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idProjectInfoStatus")
private KM_ProjectInfoStatus status;
```

but I think that is wrong because at one row of my first table it is associated a specific single row of the second table. But maybe I am missing something about how Hibernate work.

Can you help me to understand what I am missing? What it work? Why I have **@ManyToOne** instead **@OneToOne**?

Tnx

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on how you want to model  things. In terms of Database structure, `OneToOne` and `ManyToOne` are implemented in the same way:

- One or more `JoinColumns` which makes a foreign key pointing to the primary key of the other table.

So both solutions correctly map to your database, but it depends if you want to allow several `KM_ProjectInfo` to point to the same `KM_ProjectInfoStatus`, or only allow a single one.

Note that, even though you would declare a OneToOne, you could still end up with multiple `KM_ProjectInfo` pointing to the same `KM_ProjectInfoStatus` if you don't manipulate Hibernate properly.

Here you did not declare the reverse relationship, but if you did, the declaration would have to be different:

- In case of a `OneToOne`, you would have a `KM_ProjectInfo` member
- In case of a `OneToMany` (reverse of `ManyToOne`), you would have a `Collection<KM_ProjectInfo>` member

Comment: mmm so do you mean that using OneToMany more instance of KM_ProjectInfo can be related to the same KM_ProjectInfoStatus instance? And if I use OneToOne a a single row of KM_ProjectInfo is related to a single specific instance of KM_ProjectInfoStatus and no other instance (table row) of KM_ProjectInfo could be related to this instance (row) of KM_ProjectInfoStatus? Is this the meaning of your explaination?

Answer (score 0):

From the description it seems you want to have one-to-one relationship. That is the project entity should have its very own status not shared by any other project. You could achieve this by using @OneToOne as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KM_PROJECT")
public class KM_ProjectInfo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idProjectInfo;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idProjectInfoStatus")
    private KM_ProjectInfoStatus status;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS")
public class KM_ProjectInfoStatus implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idProjectInfoStatus;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy="idProjectInfoStatus")
   private KM_ProjectInfo project;
}
```

This way you can have specific status for the KM_PROJECT.

Coming back to @ManyToOne, you will want to have this if you want to share the same status with multiple projects, but that's not what you want in your case. I have tried to explain mappings in simple way here [One-to-One mapping](http://blog.techdynamic.me/jpa-mappings-one-to-one-mapping/).